# Problems on converting Database with ddlutils

Tags: java, mysql, ddlutils

I have to convert a mysql-database into a java (derby) database.
This works fine with ant-tasks, absolutely no problem. 
Unfortunately not all the tables out of the orginin-database may be used in the target-database.
As i found no chance to filter tables by name in the ant-tasks of ddlUtils,
i consider to write a small java-application using ddlUtils.jar.

But trying this, i am not even able to extract schema and data out themysql-database. The examples in the ddlUtils-api explain to less for a beginner like me.

Is there a more comprehensive example how to deal with this Problem?

My Plan was to split the work into this steps:

- getting the db-schema from the origin-database (filtered by TableNames)
- getting the data from the origin-database (filtered by TableNames)
- creating the schema in the target-database (Java) by using the reduced db-schema
- inserting the data in the target-database by using the reduced content.

In the api-section "Read the model from a live database" is the method platform.readModelFromDatabase(String) used for this action, but i was not able to instantiate a Platform-object by now which let me call the method
without lots of exceptions.

lots of thanks
Alf

Answer (score 3):

Well 6 months without an answer .. If you're still interested I was trying to find resources on the web about DdlUtils but unfortunately they were very poor. But these sites helped me to find a way to start:

http://www.sienaproject.com/documentation-jdbc.html

http://codeblow.com/questions/database-migration/

http://numberformat.wordpress.com/tag/ddlutils/

I'm using this code to initialize the MySQL instance:

```
    MySqlPlatform platform = (MySqlPlatform) PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(datasource);
```

Hope it helps!